# How to use TypeScript on an AngularJS application (1.x) with Webpack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, refactoring

I'm following the official [tutorial to migrate from AngularJS (1.x) to Angular (2+)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html).

I managed to break my application into Components and use ES6 with a module loader, in my case Webpack, but now I'm not sure how to setup TypeScript.

I guess I need to install the TypeScript compiler and somehow tell Webpack to use it. How can I do it?

The source code is available here: https://github.com/shindarth/othello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all run:

`npm install typescript awesome-typescript-loader source-map-loader --save-dev`

this will install **typescript**, **awesome-typescript-loader** and **source-map-loader** to the list of the *devDependencies* of package.json file.

- Then create the typescript compiler config file named **tsconfig.json** with a basic configuration inside:

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "commonjs",
       "target": "es5",
       "noImplicitAny": false,
       "sourceMap": true
     }
}
```

you can further customise the ts compiler options referring to the [official tsconfig.json documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

- At this point we can rename all our `*.js` files to `.ts`.
- Note that wherever we were importing angularjs using:

`import angular from 'angular';`

we need to change it with:

`import * as angular from 'angular';`

- Finally we can tell WebPack to use the ts compiler to compile our *.ts source files.

So edit the file **webpack.config.js** as follows:

1) Edit the entry file name (since we renamed it and changed its extension to .ts).

In my case it was `./app/index.js` before, change to:

```
entry: {
    app: './app/index.ts'
},
```

2) then below add the following:

```
// Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
devtool: "source-map",
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
},
module: {
    rules: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

        // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
},
```